# Java regex for support Unicode?

Tags: java, regex, unicode, cjk

To match A to Z, we will use regex:

> [A-Za-z]

How to allow regex to match utf8 characters entered by user? For example Chinese words like 环保部

Comment: In Java 7, Unicode regex is supported with `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag or embeddable `(?U)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions

Answer (score 144, accepted):

What you are looking for are Unicode properties.

e.g. `\p{L}` is any kind of letter from any language

So a regex to match such a Chinese word could be something like

```
\p{L}+
```

There are many such properties, for more details see [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

Another option is to use the modifier

`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`

In Java 7 there is a new property `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` that enables the Unicode version of the predefined character classes [see my answer here for some more details and links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500409/626273)

You could do something like this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

and `\w` would match all letters and all digits from any languages (and of course some word combining characters like `_`).

Comment: To match words like Da̱nx̱a̱laga̱litła̱n, do we need to instruct the pattern matcher to combine the diacritics?

Comment: It's really frustrating that the javadoc for `Pattern` doesn't specifically say "`\P{L}` is any letter at all". Instead, you have to read their example "`[\p{L}&&[^\p{Lu}]]`" carefully to see that it introduces another predefined class which is mentioned nowhere else on the page.

Answer (score 16):

To address NLS support and avoid accepting English special character, we can use below pattern...

**[a-zA-Z0-9 \u0080-\u9fff]*+**

For UTF code point reference: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl

Code snippet:

```
    String vowels = "అఆఇఈఉఊఋఌఎఏఐఒఓఔౠౡ";
    String consonants = "కఖగఘఙచఛజఝఞటఠడఢణతథదధనపఫబభమయరఱలళవశషసహ";
    String signsAndPunctuations = "కఁకంకఃకాకికీకుకూకృకౄకెకేకైకొకోకౌక్కౕకౖ";
    String symbolsAndNumerals = "౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯";
    String engChinesStr = "ABC導字會";


    Pattern ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPACE_PATTERN_TELUGU = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9 \\u0c00-\\u0c7f]*+");
    System.out.println(ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPACE_PATTERN_TELUGU.matcher(vowels)
            .matches());


    Pattern ALPHANUMERIC_AND_SPACE_PATTERN_CHINESE = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9 \\u4e00-\\u9fff]*+");

    Pattern ENGLISH_ALPHANUMERIC_SPACE_AND_NLS_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9 \\u0080-\\u9fff]*+");

    System.out.println(ENGLISH_ALPHANUMERIC_SPACE_AND_NLS_PATTERN.matcher(engChinesStr)
            .matches());
```

Answer (score 9):

To match individual characters, you can simply include them in an a character class, either as literals or via the `\u03FB` syntax.

Obviously you often cannot list all allowed characters in ideographic languages. To make the regex treat unicode characters according to their type or code block, various other escapes are supported that are defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Look at the section "Unicode support", particularly the references to the `Character` class and to the Unicode Standard itself.

Comment: how to mataches multiple utf8 characters entered by user example 环保部, because user will be entering randomly number of characters

Comment: It's just like matching multiple Latin characters: `[a-z]+` or `[a-z]{3}` or even `[a-z]{2,10}`. The only thing different is what you allow in the character class that the quantifier applies to.

Answer (score 4):

- the Java regular expression API works on the `char` type
- the `char` type is implicitly UTF-16
- if you have UTF-8 data you will need to transcode it to UTF-16 on input if this is not already being done

Unicode is the universal set of characters and UTF-8 can describe all of it (including control characters, punctuation, symbols, letters, etc.) You will have to be more specific about what you want to include and what you want to exclude. Java regular expressions uses the `\p{category}` syntax to match codepoints by [category](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn36/). See the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/standard/standard.html) for the [list](http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn36/Categories.txt) of categories.

If you want to identify and separate words in a sequence of ideographs, you will need to look at a more sophisticated API. I would start with the [`BreakIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html#getWordInstance%28%29) type.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Java 9, you can also use `\X` to match any Unicode extended grapheme cluster. See more at [Java Doc: Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).