# Using Unicode regular expressions in Java to match any Unicode character

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I am trying to use the Java regex matcher to search and replace. However, after it failed to match a certain string, I noticed that the expression ".*" seems to fail to match certain Unicode characters (in my case it was a `\u2028 LINE SEPARATOR` character).

This is what I have at the moment (match an XML element with any text in between):

```
String segSourceSearch = "<source(.?)>(.*?)</source>";
String segSourceReplace = "<source$1>$2</source><target$1>$2</target>";
myString = myString.replaceAll(segSourceSearch, segSourceReplace);
```

Basically, what this is supposed to do is duplicate the element. 
But how can I modify the regex `(.*?)` to match any Unicode character between `<source>` and `</source>`? Is there a built-in pattern in Java? If not, is there anything in ICU4J that I could use? (I haven't been able to find a regex matcher in ICU4J).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression

Comment: Take a look here:
[Similar case][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. But this solution is for matching characters from the Letter class. This would not match non-letter characters, such as the Line Separator.

Comment: @marw, you seem to have a typo in your regex.  I'm pretty sure `(.?)` was supposed to be `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 2):

[Pattern.DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL):

> Enables dotall mode.
>   In dotall mode, the expression . matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators.
>
> Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?s).

So the pattern you are looking for is `(?s).*?`, for capturing you still have to enclose it in braces, `((?s).*?)`, but you can also place the `(?s)` at the beginning of the entire expression to enable the `DOTALL` mode for the entire regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. @Alan, you are correct. That was indeed a typo.

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution. In the meantime, I have gone down a different route. The text that I wanted to process was in XML and it turned that my transformation was easier to do using XML functions. Thanks anyway. I will bear the Dotall patter in mind for the future.