# replaceAll, how to change letters

Tags: java, string, replaceall

What would I need instead of "" to replace all alphabetical letters  with * ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Tere, TULNUKAS, 1234!";
    String t = asenda(s); // "****, ********, 12345!" <---- example 
}

public static String asenda(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("", "*");
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `replaceAll([a-zA-Z],"*")` ?

Comment: Beware of any non-English characters with that regex... a far better idea is the Unicode letter category: `\\p{L}`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use regular expression:

```
return s.replaceAll("[a-zA-z]", "*")
```

Answer (score 2):

For *every letter* you can use the `[a-zA-Z]` regex

For example:

```
public static String asenda(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "*");
}
```

Comment: @RohitJain Yet it isn't a plain string, either. Something to watch out for :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Didn't understand your comment. :(

Comment: @RohitJain `$` and `\ ` are special chars there. Try making a regex to replace each `\ ` with `\\ ` :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Indeed. `$` is used for referencing capture groups. :)

Answer (score 2):

Proper solution with unicode characters support is

```
public static String asenda(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\\p{L}", "*");
}
```

> You can match a single character belonging to the "letter" category with `\p{L}`.

Source: [Unicode Regular Expressions/Unicode Categories](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category)

More information:

- [Java regex for support Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html