# Get string inside parenthesis Java

Tags: java

I want get the value inside []. For example, this string:

```
 String str ="[D][C][B][A]Hello world!";
```

and I want an array which contains item DCBA, how should I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it always one character per square brackets?

Comment: Apparently it isn't. Note that that's relevant information. A char is not the same as a string in java. And it matters for regex matching as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try with regex if there is only one character inside [].

- Here `Matcher#group()` is used that groups any matches found inside parenthesis ().
- Here escape character `\` is used to escape the [ and ] that is already a part of regex pattern itself.

Sample code:

```
String str = "[D][C][B][A]Hello world!";

List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group(1).charAt(0));
}

Character[] array = list.toArray(new Character[list.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

---

Try this one if there is more than one character inside []

```
String str = "[DD][C][B][A]Hello world!";

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\w*)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    list.add(m.group(1));
}

String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

---

#### Pattern description

```
\w      A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
.       Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
X*      X, zero or more times
```

Read more about here [JAVA Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what if there is more than just one word in the parenthesis?

Comment: Go with second solution

Comment: this works perfect for english! but this does not work for say chinese characters inside []. Any idea how to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Find it here [Java regex for support Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode)

Answer (score 0):

This code is simple

```
  String str ="[D][C][B][A]Hello world!";
  String[] s =  str.split("\\[");
  StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
  for (String o: s) {
    if (o.length() > 0){
      String[] s2 =  o.split("\\]");
      b.append(s2[0]);
    }
  }
  char[] c = b.toString().toCharArray();
  System.out.println(new String(c));
```