# How to validate string using java

Tags: java, regex, string

I looked for a solution online, but I didn't find any.

I want to validate input string and check if it contains only ALLOWED characters.

My problem is, that I have "special" alphabet which contains "ěščřžýáí".

For normal English alphabet I can use regex like this `A-Za-z`.

But what to use for quick check in my language?

My language contains following chars:

```
String ALLOWED_CHARS = "AÁBCČDĎEÉĚFGHChIÍJKLMNŇOÓPQRŘSŠTŤUÚŮVWXYÝZŽaábcčdďeéěfghchiíjklmnňoópqrřsštťuúůvwxyýzž";
```

Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regex for support Unicode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode)

Comment: @ashutosh I don't want allow chinase character.

Comment: try to read a couple of answers there, I am pretty sure you will find your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use string.matches("[" + ALLOWED_CHARS +"]*") to this check, for example:

```
String ALLOWED_CHARS = "AÁBCČDĎEÉĚFGHChIÍJKLMNŇOÓPQRŘSŠTŤUÚŮVWXYÝZŽaábcčdďeéěfghchiíjklmnňoópqrřsštťuúůvwxyýzž";
String s1 = "ĎE88É"; 
boolean flag1 = s1.matches("[" + ALLOWED_CHARS +"]*"); // false
String s2 = "ĎEÉ";
boolean flag2 = s2.matches("[" + ALLOWED_CHARS +"]*"); // true
```