# How to replace all non-supplementary chars, but leave all supplementary as is?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, negation, supplementary

I have a problem with Java Regex applied on supplementary chars

```
String x = new StringBuilder().appendCodePoint(0x10001).toString();
// x == "" (char['\uD800', '\uDC01']) - ok
String y = x.replaceAll("[\\x{10000}-\\x{10010}]", "*");
// y == "*" (char['*']) - ok
String z = x.replaceAll("[^\\x{10000}-\\x{10010}]", "*");
// z == "�*" (char['\uD800', '*']) - NOT ok
```

I'm expecting that `x == z`. What am I doing wrong?
jdk1.8.0_144

Comment: Potentially try looking at [Java regex for support Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode)

Comment: @BeeOnRope There is no anchor; it's `[^` not `^[`. The second regex is "match any character the codepoint of which is not within the range `10000-10010`".

Comment: Oops duh! Looks like a bug in Unicode handling with character classes.  Apparently the regex spuriously matches the second half of the surrogate pair and replaces it. It's consistent with incorrectly incrementing by "code unit" rather than "code point" along that code path.