# RegEx for matching specific upper and lower case patterns

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I need to check correctness of input string using regex pattern, every word should start with capital letter, also at the end there could be expression separated with "-".
String should contain at least two words or expression with dash.

e.g.

correct:

- Apple Banana Couonut-Dates
- Apple Banana
- Banana Couonut-Dates
- Couonut-Dates

incorrect:

- Apple
- Apple Banana Couonut-dates
- BanAna couonut-Dates

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z][a-z]++ )*([A-Z][a-z]++-[A-Z][a-z]++)");
pattern.matcher("Apple Banana Couonut-Dates").matches();
```

For input "Apple Banana Couonut-Dates" my expression returns false

Comment: I just put your regex and the test pattern into https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output and it works...

Comment: Thanks BretC, I checked it one more time. It seems the issue was that I was using my language special characters. When I omit them it works fine.

Comment: You could use the [Unicode properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode) for your (polish?) language characters.

Answer (score 1):

To match at least 2 uppercase words with an optional part with expression separated with `-` at the end or a single expression separated with `-` you might use:

```
^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+\b(?!-))+(?: [A-Z][a-z]+-[A-Z][a-z]+)?|(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ )?[A-Z][a-z]+-[A-Z][a-z]+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:`Non capturing group

  - `[A-Z][a-z]+` Match uppercased word
  - `(?: [A-Z][a-z]+\b(?!-))+` Repeat 1+ times uppercased word asserting what is on the right is not a `-`
  - `(?: [A-Z][a-z]+-[A-Z][a-z]+)?` Optional part, match space and uppercaseword-uppercase word
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ )?` Match optional uppercased word with space
  - `[A-Z][a-z]+-[A-Z][a-z]+`
- `)$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pUY7Pj/1)

Note in Java to double escape the backslash.