# Regex for letters and numbers with any underscores in between

Tags: java, regex, string, loops

I'm trying to create a Regex String with the following rules

1. The username is between 4 and 25 characters.
2. It must start with a letter.
3. It can only contain letters, numbers, and the underscore character.
4. It cannot end with an underscore character.

when it meets this criterion I want the output to be true otherwise false, but I only get false for my test cases, here is my code

```
public class Profile {
    public static String username(String str) {


        String regularExpression = "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_](?<=@)\\w+\\b(?!\\_){4,25}$";

        if (str.matches(regularExpression)) {
            str = "true";
        }
        else if (!str.matches(regularExpression)) {
            str = "false";

        }
        return str;
    }
```

Main class

```
Profile profile = new profile();

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(profile.username(s.nextLine()));
```

input

```
"aa_"
"u__hello_world123"
```

output

```
false
false
```

Fixed: thanks to everyone who contributed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,24}$(?<!_)
^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,24}$(?<!_)
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,23}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
^\p{Alpha}[a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,23}\p{Alnum}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g7jOeV/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,24}` / `\w{3,24}` - three to twenty four ASCII letters, digits or underscores
- `$` - end of string
- `(?<!_)` - a negative lookbehind that makes sure there is no `_` (at the end of string).

Note that `{3,24}` is used and not `{4,25}` because the first `[a-zA-Z]` pattern already matches a single char.

Usage:

```java
public static String username(String str) {
    return Boolean.toString( str.trim().matches("[a-zA-Z]\\w{3,24}$(?<!_)") );
    // return Boolean.toString( str.trim().matches("\\p{Alpha}[a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,23}\\p{Alnum}") );
    // return Boolean.toString( str.trim().matches("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,23}[a-zA-Z0-9]") );
}
```

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/FcGISJ):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static String username(String str) {
        return Boolean.toString( str.trim().matches("[a-zA-Z]\\w{3,24}$(?<!_)") );
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(username("u__hello_world123")); // => true
        System.out.println(username("aa_")); // => false
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I still get false for both cases, is it something that has to do with my code?

Comment: @PlusUltra I suggest trimming the line first, then check. Note that in `matches`, the first anchor is redundant since the whole string must match the regex.

Comment: Same behavior can be archieved without any lookbehind to be more readable:
`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]{2,23}[a-zA-Z0-9]$`

Comment: thanks but still not working, it switched from false to true

Comment: If you literally input `"u__hello_world123"` in the console it results in false because of the quotation marks. They are not necessary since the input on the console is always interpreted as a string. When omitting them works perfectly fine for me. If that's not the case for you, you need to post more of your code.

Comment: @PlusUltra I added testing demo code to the answer, please check. Note that trimming helps get rid of any trailing line breaks you may get when scanning for lines. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [`\p{L}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) any letter at the start, `\w` [word characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) between and `\p{Alnum}` in the end.

```
(?U)^\p{L}\w{2,23}\p{Alnum}$
```

As a Java String:

```
final String regex = "(?U)^\\p{L}\\w{2,23}\\p{Alnum}$";
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/J4YgLH/2) - Thank you @Thefourthbird for providing [a Java demo at ideone.com](https://ideone.com/dkizXF)

---

The [`(?U)` modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) will turn on [unicode support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10894689/5527985) for predefined character classes, e.g. for `\w`. Instead of the embedded flag also `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` can be used to enable.

Comment: Is this not good? Seems ok right.. https://ideone.com/KyCWhZ

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you, I included your demo, hope that's ok!

Comment: But of course it is