# Splitting words from text using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to filter the given text to get all words, including apostrophes (can't is considered a single word).

```
Para = "'hello' world '"
```

I am splitting the text using

```
String[] splits = Para.split("[^a-zA-Z']");
```

Expected output:

```
hello world
```

But it is giving:

```
'hello' world '
```

I get everything right, except a single apostrophe (') and 'hello' are not getting filtered by the above regex.

How can I filter these two things?

Comment: You want to split a `String` into words? Use `\\b` - this is the regex shortcut for "word boundary". It might well do the trick depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: It can't take care of the case of `can't`. And by the way, what is your original string? I think the result should be correct with your code here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use the Java word boundary with apostrophes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769652/how-do-you-use-the-java-word-boundary-with-apostrophes)

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Special characters are not getting filtered by this.

Comment: @HariChaudhary yes, I forgot about the broken nature of `\\b` in Java. See the duplicate I linked.

Comment: @nhahtdh "'hello' world" , my code gives 'hello' world

Comment: @HariChaudhary: What is your expected result, then? (Again, please edit your question with a clear example, the expected result and what you actually get).

Comment: @nhahtdh presumably if the apostrophe is _inside_ a word it should be treated as part of that word as if it is _outside_ it should be treated as a boundary.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Then the duplicate question most probably doesn't have an answer, then.

Comment: @nhahtdh It in fact does.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: The problem is completely different in fact. The other one tries to search a string. This question is about splitting. (And by the way `\b` in Java is no longer broken when used with `(?U)` flag in Java 7, but by definition, it will split at `'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're looking for a `'` where either the next or previous character is *not* a letter.

The regex I came up with to do this, contained in some test code:

```
String str = "bob can't do 'well'";
String[] splits = str.split("(?:(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z])'|'(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)|[^a-zA-Z'])+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splits));
```

**Explanation:**

`(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z])'` - matches a `'` where the previous character is not a letter, or we're at the start of the string.
`'(?=[^a-zA-Z]|$)` - matches a `'` where the next character is not a letter, or we're at the end of the string.
`[^a-zA-Z']` - not a letter or `'`.
`(?:...)+` - one or more of any of the above (the `?:` is just to make it [a non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)).

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more on regex lookaround (`(?<=...)` and `(?=...)`).

**Simplification:**

The regex can be simplified to the below by using negative lookaround:

```
"(?:(?<![a-zA-Z])'|'(?![a-zA-Z])|[^a-zA-Z'])+"
```

Comment: `(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z])` can be written as `(?<![a-zA-Z])`

Answer (score 1):

A Unicode version, without lookarounds:

```
String TestInput = "This voilà München is the test' 'sentence' that I'm willing to split";

String[] splits = TestInput.split("'?[^\\p{L}']+'?");

for (String t : splits) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

`\p{L}` is matching a character with the [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) "Letter"

This splits on a non letter, non ' sequence, including a leading or trailing ' in the split.

Output:

> This
>   voilà
>   München
>   is
>   the
>   test
>   sentence
>   that
>   I'm
>   willing
>   to
>   split

To handle leading and trailing ', just add them as alternatives

```
TestInput.split("'?[^\\p{L}']+'?|^'|'$")
```

Comment: It fails for "'hello' world ' can't" (Leading ' in the sentence)?

Comment: @aNish, yes it doesn't handle those cases. I added a suggestion to my answer. This will add an empty entry in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a word as a sequence that:

- Must start and end with English alphabet `a-zA-Z`
- May contain apostrophe (`'`) within.

Then you can use the following regex in `Matcher.find()` loop to extract matches:

```
[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z']*[a-zA-Z])?
```

Sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z']*[a-zA-Z])?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/xT2mA6)<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup> The demo uses PCRE flavor regex, but the result should not be different from Java for this regex</sup>