# Extract and split words from text and list them in order of occurrence using only shell terminal regex

Tags: regex, list, shell, split, cpu-word

I have this text bellow (in this format), and I want the words to be separated and placed one by one in the order they occur in a vertical list like this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/21672824/10824251. I try `egrep -vi "'?[^\\p{L}']+'?|^'|'$" mytext.txt > output.txt` but I got no result just that output.txt had no (empty) content.

My text:

> Teaching psychology is the part of education psychology that refers to
>   school education. As will be seen later, both have the same goal:
>   study, explain and understand the processes of behavioral change that
>   are produce in people as a consequence of their participation in
>   activities educational What gives an entity proper to teaching
>   psychology is the nature and the characteristics of the educational
>   activities that exist at the base of the of behavioral change studied.

My text in Portuguese:

> A psicologia do ensino é a parte da psicologia da educacão que se
>   refere à educacão escolar. Como se verá mais adiante, ambas têm um
>   mesmo objetivo: estudar, explicar e compreender os processos de
>   mudanca comportamental que se produzem nas pessoas como uma
>   conseqüência da sua participacão em atividades educativas. O que
>   confere uma entidade própria à psicologia do ensino é a natureza e
>   as caracterís- ticas das atividades educativas que existem na base
>   dos processos de mudanca comportamental estudados.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regex code in the example in Java is the element I wanted to point out in the post. I usually use egrep -vi before, so it would be `egrep -vi "'?[^\\p{L}']+'?|^'|'$" mytext.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Note that regex is to be used in a *`split`* command. `grep` is not splitting, it is extracting. You want something like `grep -oE '[[:alnum:]]+'` or  `grep -oE '[[:alpha:]]+' mytext.txt > output.txt`

Comment: And how can I do this without using `split` and the code understands where it starts and for a word.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/eB5FFB. Do you need to also get numbers? What way do you want to tokenize the text?

Comment: Thankful, it really works. But I will need to work with texts with diacritics such as these accents `^`, `~`, etc. I did a test and it breaks line when it finds these signs. I may have to open a new question for this.

Comment: Do you mean you need to split with whitespace? `grep -oE '[^[:space:]]+' mytext.txt > output.txt` Do not post the same question, just explain what criteria the extracting pattern should meet.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have added the text in Portuguese having the accents I mentioned. Please try to execute the same code for this new text and you will see that it breaks the lines where there are accents in the resulting file.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew grep -oE '[^[:space:]]+' has solved with accents too, sorry for not realizing it before.

Comment: `grep -oP '[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+'` may work, too.

Comment: ThankX:) @WiktorStribiżew. `grep -oP '[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+'` worked correctly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to tokenize texts by whitespace:

```
grep -o '[^[:space:]][^[:space:]]*' mytext.txt > output.txt
grep -o '[^[:space:]]\{1,\}' mytext.txt > output.txt
grep -oE '[^[:space:]]+' mytext.txt > output.txt
```

Or, you may extract all chunks of 1+ letters (`\p{L}`), diacritics (`\p{M}`) and numbers (`\p{N}`) with the PCRE regex like:

```
grep -oP '[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}]+'  mytext.txt > output.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/BfEp2d). You will need [`pcregrep`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22704387/3832970) on MacOS for this to work.

Comment: I use arch linux. Thanks!! All the suggested commands worked, I tested it here. Grateful for suggestions and ideas for testing.