# using regex to see if string contains this word only, not within another word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that matches these strings in a string; however, it is matching non-words ( parts-of-words ) as well.

For example `city` is matched as it contains `it`. However, I want only the string it to be matched it if it the only characters between whitespace. So `it` or `he` would match, but not city or where.

Here is the regex ( pretty basic and simple ): `they|he|she|her|him|them|it`.

How can I get it to match these words if the word is only this?

Comment: *" I want only the string it to be matched it if it the only characters between whitespace"* add whitespaces to your expression then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *word boundaries* to denote the beginning and ending of a word.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

So your regex would become something on the order of:

`\b(they|he|she|her|him|them|it)\b`

[Check it out](http://regex101.com/r/hP5lV4)

It should be noted that this regular expression **won't** match words containing apostrophes, e.g. *can't*, *won't*, etc. For a discussion of this, see the following Stackoverflow post:

[How do you use the Java word boundary with apostrophes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769652/how-do-you-use-the-java-word-boundary-with-apostrophes)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put an word boundary before the words,

```
(?:\bthey\b|\bhe\b|\bshe\b|\bher\b|\bhim\b|\bthem\b|\bit\b)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:...) # Non captuaring groups
\b      # Word boundary(It matches between a word character and a non word character)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mX1eT7)